# Numeric matrix is taking far more memory than it should - R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am creating a document term matrix (dtm for short) for a Naive Bayes implementation (I know there is a function for this, but I have to code it myself for homework.)  I wrote a function that successfully creates the dtm, the problem is that the resulting matrix is taking up too much memory.  For example a 100 x 32000 matrix (of 0's and 1's) is 24MB in size!  This is resulting in crashy behavior in r when trying to work with the full 10k documents. The functions follow and a toy example is in the last 3 lines.  Can anyone spot why the "sparser" function in particular is returning such memory-intensive results?

```
listAllWords <- function(docs)
{
  str1 <- strsplit(x=docs, split="\\s", fixed=FALSE)
  dictDupl <- unlist(str1)[!(unlist(str1) %in% stopWords)]
  dictionary <- unique(dictDupl)
}

#function to create the sparse matrix of words as they appear in each article segment
sparser <- function (docs, dictionary) 
{
  num.docs <- length(docs) #dtm rows
  num.words <- length(dictionary) #dtm columns
  dtm <- mat.or.vec(num.docs,num.words) # Instantiate dtm of zeroes
  for (i in 1:num.docs)
  {
    doc.temp <- unlist(strsplit(x=docs[i], split="\\s", fixed=FALSE)) #vectorize words
    num.words.doc <- length(doc.temp)
    for (j in 1:num.words.doc)
    {
      ind <- which(dictionary == doc.temp[j]) #loop over words and find index in dict.
      dtm[i,ind] <- 1 #indicate this word is in this document
    }
  }
  return(dtm)
}


docs <- c("the first document contains words", "the second document is also made of words", "the third document is words and a number 4")
dictionary <- listAllWords(docs)
dtm <- sparser(docs,dictionary)
```

If it makes any difference I am running this in R Studio in Mac OSX, 64 bit

Comment: Small side note: your example code isn't totally self contained, we don't have `stopWords`. Anyway, you only really needed an example of the matrix itself, like I did below.

Answer (score 1):

Surely part of your problem is that you are not actually storing integers, but doubles. Note:

```
m <- mat.or.vec(100,32000)
m1 <- matrix(0L,100,32000)

> object.size(m)
25600200 bytes
> object.size(m1)
12800200 bytes
```

And note the lack of the "L" in the code for `mat.or.vec`:

```
> mat.or.vec
function (nr, nc) 
if (nc == 1L) numeric(nr) else matrix(0, nr, nc)
<bytecode: 0x1089984d8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You will also want to explicitly assign `1L`, otherwise R will convert everything to doubles upon the first assignment, I think. You can verify that by simply assigning one value of `m1` above the value 1 and recheck the object size.

I should probably also mention the function `storage.mode` which can help you to verify that you're using integers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @joran!  I tried using `matrix(0L,nr,nc)` in the function instead of mat.or.vec, however the resulting matrix was the same size as before.  Using `storage.mode(dtm) <- "integer"` cut the size in half, but it still seems huge.  Or...maybe I just don't know enough about how much storage matrices should take...

Comment: @datapaRty Remember that I said that changing `mat.or.vec` wasn't enough. The first time you assign `1` (or anything else non-integer) it will convert everything to double.

Comment: I did change out `mat.or.vec` for `matrix` and used the `0L` assignment.  I rechecked using the `1L` assignment in `matrix` and it again shifted to doubles, as you suggested it would.  Since I can only halve the required storage by converting to integer maybe the solution is to write a smarter algorithm that results in a smaller matrix (say 32000 x 5 (which is the number of classes for the classifier.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store 0/1 values economically, I would suggest `raw` type.

```
m8 <- matrix(0,100,32000)
m4 <- matrix(0L,100,32000)
m1 <- matrix(raw(1),100,32000)
```

The `raw` type takes just 1 byte per value:

```
> object.size(m8)
25600200 bytes
> object.size(m4)
12800200 bytes
> object.size(m1)
3200200 bytes
```

Here is how to operate with it:

```
> m1[2,2] = as.raw(1)
> m1[2,2]
[1] 01
> as.integer(m1[2,2])
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to be economical look at the [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ff) and [bit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bit) packages.